# Drag and drop sort table row without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

The most table row drag and drop sort example on the internet is using jQuery sortable. I need an example to show me to sort the table row without using jQuery at all. 
Please see below for the table setup.

```
<table>
   <tr id="row-a">
      <td> Item A</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row-b">
      <td> Item B</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can write your own custom method to do the sort...

Comment: For drag and drop look here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API
but keep in mind the feature is sketchy as of yet so you might need to go through the steps here: http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/ 

The sorting is should just be splicing the array of child elements.  You should be able to get there by looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice